# Content jumps around on inserting or updating TextBoxes/DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax

My .aspx form dances around when I tab from a textBox to another textBox, but the worst jumping around occurs when I tab to or from a DropDownList.

All I have is few textboxes. nothing complex, no gridviews, no labels.

What am I doing wrong?

IE8 .NET 3.5

<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Requestor.aspx.vb" Inherits="RCCRSAdmin.Requestor"  MasterPageFile="~/RCCRS.Master" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

Requestor 







    
    
    
    Centre
    
    
    
    
    
    
    Username
    
    
    
    
        
    
    --%>
    
    
    
    User Type
     
    
     
    
       

    
    
    Staff No
    
    
    
    
    
        
    
    --%>
    
    
     

    
    
    Password
    
    
    
    
        
    
    
        
    
    Forename 
             
    
    
        
    
    
    
    
    Surname
    
    
    
        
    
       
    
    
    Email 
             
    
    
        
    
    
    
    
    Mobile
    
    
    
        
    
     
    
    
    Tel Office

Comment: Can you provide an example page?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "dance around"

Comment: Can you repost that code indented 4 spaces/1 tab so that the SO code formatter picks it up?

Comment: I think what lakiro was asking was you to highlight the code and click the 'code sample' button (the one with the 010101 icon)

Answer (score 0):

Without any examples to look at it's difficult to say but here are some things to look out for that can cause browser reflow.

1. The CSS pseudo-class :focus might be defining an alternate border or margin width.
2. OnFocus/onBlur events on elements that trigger JavaScript to alter the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "dance around". Is this a tab index issue? In which case, the TabIndex attribute on the element should help.

Comment: I have the TabIndex set properly, it must be something else. Thanx though.

Comment: You still haven't explained what dance around means.